# Search tag within category

Tags: categories, tags, archives, list

How do I search a tag within a category? like if a user is viewing a post that belongs to category "Romance" and the user clicks on one of the tags like for example "blonde" it should list all posts tagged "blonde" within category "Romance". How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure how to do this, but I found a plugin that seems to be able to do this.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/tdo-tag-fixes/

Comment: that plugin is old and it doesn't work with the latest wordpress version 3.5.1